# Trigger que al insertar en una tabla inserte en otra

Tags: sql, oracle

He tratado de practicar triggers en oracles pl/sql, que por ejemplo tenga una tabla que tenga valores como precios de un determinado producto y que si estos están un valor por debajo de 500 los ingrese en otra tabla que se llama *pdescuentooferta*, pero que solo inserte los valores del ID y el Titulo, y me da error de compilación.

```sql
create table librodigital(
  codigo number primary key,
  titulo varchar2(40) not null,
  autor varchar2(30) not null,
  editorial varchar(20) not null,
  precio number not null
 );

create table pdescuentooferta(
  codigo number primary key,
  titulo varchar2(40) not null
 );
```

Lo que trato de hacer es que si se inserta un libro digital por un precio menor a 500 este no se inserte en *librodigital* sino en *pdescuentooferta* solo con su código y título. No sé por qué me está
dando error de compilación.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_precio_menor_quinientos
BEFORE INSERT ON librodigital FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
precio NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF precio < 500 THEN
    INSERT INTO pdescuentooferta VALUES(CODIGO, TITULO);
    END IF;
    IF precio >= 500 THEN
    INSERT INTO librodigital VALUES(CODIGO, TITULO,AUTOR,EDITORIAL,PRECIO);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Comparte el error que te sale, no somos adivinos.

Comment: LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
5/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

5/39      PL/SQL: ORA-00984: columna no permitida aquí

8/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

8/51      PL/SQL: ORA-00984: columna no permitida aquí

Errores: comprobar log de compilador

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el error _en la pregunta_. Lee [ask].

Comment: En los insert condicionados no estás haciendo referencia en ninguna parte a los valores del insert que dispara el trigger (cuando intentas insertar en librodigital). ¿Qué significa insertar `CODIGO` en pdescuentooferta? De dónde sale `CODIGO`? Revisa.

Comment: finalmente me sirvió con esto CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_precio_menor_quinientos
BEFORE INSERT ON librodigital FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF :new.precio < 500 THEN
    INSERT INTO pdescuentooferta VALUES(:new.codigo, :new.titulo);
    END IF;

END;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_precio_menor_quinientos

BEFORE INSERT ON librodigital FOR EACH ROW
 
DECLARE 

BEGIN 

IF :new.precio < 500 THEN

 INSERT INTO pdescuentooferta VALUES(:new.codigo, :new.titulo);

 END IF; 

END;
```

Ya lo pude solucionar.